# C# DataGridView handles generic class setter excpetion instead of DataError

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, datagridview

Well, first of all I have search for about sometime and didn't found any answer that points to my problem.

I have this situation:

- I have a `DataGridView` which has a `BindingList<Person>` as `DataSource`.
- This `DataGridView` can be edited directly on the `DataGridViewCell`.

In the `class Person` I have a property height:

```
public int Height
{
    get { return _height; }            
    set 
    {
       if (!int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out _height))
           throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid value.");                
    }
}
```

My Problem:

When I edit a cell directly on the grid and put a invalid value for that field (anything but `int`), the `DataGridView` raise an `Exception` before it passes the value through the property setter. But, if I pass a valid value, it will pass through the property setter but it will never raise that `Exception` because... it's valid.

How do I tell the `DataGridView` that the `Exception` that I want to throw is the setter `Exception` of my `class`?

Comment: `int.TryParse(value.ToString())` in **int** property setter doesn't make sense. it will always be parsed. if you make property of type `string`, grid will accept any value and your validation will throw exception if necessary

Comment: if I pass a string 'abc' in my `DataGridViewCell` correspondent of my property (remembering that the `DataGridView`is bounded by a `BindingList`) it will not be a valid int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an int property, you don't need such validation:

```
set 
{
   if (!int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out _height))
       throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid value.");                
}
```

Because the value is always int.

When your property is int, the passed value always will be int, and the string that entered in `DatGridView` will never pass to your int property. So your setter never reached this way.

DataGridView will throw a format exception when you write a string in that cell, you can hanlde [`DataError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DatGridView`

```
private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //Hanlde exception and perform what you need for example show your custom message:
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid value.")   
}
```

You can use properties of [`DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerroreventargs(v=vs.110).aspx):

- **`Cancel`**: Gets or sets a value indicating whether the event should be canceled.
- **`ColumnIndex`**: Gets the column index of the cell that the event occurs for.
- **`Context`**:Gets details about the state of the DataGridView when the error occurred.
- **`Exception`**: Gets the exception that represents the error.
- **`RowIndex`**: Gets the row index of the cell that the event occurs for.
- **`ThrowException`**: Gets or sets a value indicating whether to throw the exception after the DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler delegate is finished with it.

For example suppose you have string property that in setter, you check if length of passed value is greater than 10 you will throw "Some friendly message". In this case the entered data will be passed to the property and your validation will execute.

As another example, Suppose you have an integer property and in setter you will check if value is less than 0 then will throw "Some other friendly message.", in this case if user enters a "blahblah", it doesn't reach your setter and `DataError` will catch it, but if the user enters -5 or 10 the setter will be reached and for -5 the exception will raise.

Comment: I need this validation because you can write basically anything on the DataGridView, not only a int. 

And I already have this `DataError` method. But the problem is that I wanna throw the excption of my setter and not have to re-write it in the `DataError`. I noticed that when the value is valid it will pass in setter and do the validation (which is pointless since the value is valid), but when it's not valid it will go to the `DataError`

Comment: @NatanielRichardt When your property is int, the passed value always will be int, and the string that entered in `DatGridView` will never pass to your int property. So your setter never reached this way.

Comment: @NatanielRichardt if you got the point, let me now what is you r actual requirement, maybe I have some offer for you:)

Comment: If the value is a valid int it it will pass in the set, otherwise it will pass in the `DataError` and never reach the set validation on the property. I have many other fields bounded to this `DataGridView` by my `BindingList`, and I wanna use the property set validation of each one.

Comment: @NatanielRichardt You are saying "If the value is a valid int it it will pass in the set, otherwise it will pass in the DataError and never reach the set validation on the property". As I said and you said too, Please pay attention!!! **You can't pass the entered string value to those int properties.** So what's the problem and what do you want to do?

Comment: So, you're saying that there is no way to tell the grid that I don't wanna use its DataError validation and instead use my setter validation?

Comment: @NatanielRichardt Technically No, but in this case Yes. For example suppose you have string property that in setter, you check if length of passed value is greater than 10 you will throw "Some friendly message", It will work. As another example, Suppose you have an integer property and in setter you will check if value is less than 0 then will throw "Some other friendly message.", in this case if user enters a string, it doesn't reach your setter and `DataError` will catch it, but if the user enters -5 or 10 the setter will be reached and for -5 the exception will raise.

Comment: @NatanielRichardt I'll Edit the answer and add this example to be more useful for future readers. Hope you find it helpful:)

Comment: @NatanielRichardt Do you have a better vision know?

Comment: I tried to mark your response as useful but I don't have 15 rep yet... Well, thanks for it anyway! I thought I could use the set validation in case of invalid cast too... Thanks again! :)

Comment: Done! Have a great day :)

Comment: @NatanielRichardt And you too  :)